# I need some suggestion to develop an spring batch application

Tags: spring-batch

I need to send one template to greet the person on birthday.

so, I want to keep the whole html template in database . And that template should automatically send by spring batch email scheduler to that person.

i need some ideas.

Comment: Please review how to provide minimal reproducible example code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should store this file in database (BLOB). It doesn't need to be in batch process because you just need do this once. Or you can add like your first step and verify if exist on table, is not exist insert that.

```
 <batch:job id="greetJob">
      <batch:step id="insertTemplateStep" next="sendEmailStep" >
           <batch:tasklet ref="insertTemplate" />
      </batch:step>          
      <batch:step id="sendEmailStep">
         <batch:tasklet ref="sendEmail" />
      </batch:step>
   </batch:job>
```

The second step is where you will read from the database and send email. Problably tasklet is enough because you need read from database but you don't need write, just send an e-mail.